# What is the reason that DynamicResource cannot be used in theme templates for Win 10?

Tags: wpf, themes, dynamicresource

The question is not so much because of practical necessity, but because of the desire to understand the intricacies.

In Win 7 it was possible to override keys used in theme item templates.
As far as I understand, this was due to the fact that such templates were possible in the topics:

```xml
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeControl.Background">Red</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ns:SomeControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ns:SomeControl}">
                    <Border Background="{DynamicResource SomeControl.Background}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In Win 10, DynamicResource will no longer be able to find the resource specified in the template. Therefore it is necessary to set StaticResource.
Because of this, the solutions used in Win 7 will not work in Win 10.

```xml
    <ns:SomeControl>
        <ns:SomeControl.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeControl.Background">Green</SolidColorBrush>
        </ns:SomeControl.Resources>
    </ns:SomeControl>
```

I'm wondering what caused it, what changed in the system, that it stopped working?

**Supplementing the question in connection with @BionicCode
comment.**

XAML of an example using DynamicResource in a theme template:

```xml
    <UniformGrid Columns="1" >
        <ns:SomeControl/>
        <ns:SomeControl>
            <ns:SomeControl.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeControl.Background">Green</SolidColorBrush>
            </ns:SomeControl.Resources>
        </ns:SomeControl>
    </UniformGrid>
```

The example runs on OS Win 10 and Visual Studio 2022 with all the latest updates at the moment.
Window after launch:
[image]

At the moment, I do not have a computer with Win7 available, so I cannot clearly demonstrate the execution of the same XAML.
But if someone runs the same example on Win 7, they will get this result:
[image]

Comment: Hard to believe that what you experience is related to the OS version. WPF is a high level framework. It's completely decoupled from OS details in a way that such details are hidden. From what you describe changing the OS version would break all WPF applications. WPF depends on .NET runtime which sits on top of OS details. `DynamicResource` and `StaticResource` are plain WPF level markup extensions. The resource lookup behavior or implementation is definitely not affected by OS level details. It's a simple tree traversal algorithm. Your issue must be related to something else you are missing.

Comment: However, the context that makes `DynamicResource` fail is missing. I don't see any reason why your posted example wouldn't work.

Comment: @BionicCode , Please read the supplement to my answer.